# Devise - How to trigger a sign_in on page user already has access to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Devise 3.5.2.  I have an `Item` model with a show action that anyone can access( `before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: :show`). On the show page I have a button that triggers a file upload dialog using jquery.

I only want this upload dialog to work for logged in users. If a user is logged out and they click the button I want it to bring them to my login page. When they login I want it to take them back to the show page.

How can I make it so clicking this link brings them to the login page and then after logging in they are redirected to the page they were just on and already had access to?

```
<% unless current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Upload image", item_path @item, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

This won't work because they already have access to this page.

EDIT: I tried following this link here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in but it doesn't seem to be working.

My sessions controller looks like this. Maybe my create method is causing a conflict?

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

   def new
     self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
     store_location_for(resource, params[:redirect_to])
     super
   end  


  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    if resource.deactivated?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :reactivated) if is_flashing_format?
      resource.reactivate
    end
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you need some controller specific code.

When a user clicks on the link, have the corresponding action do something like this:

```
    def image_action # Whatever the action name is
      if current_user # current user is given to you by devise
        # Do stuff that a logged in user would do
      else
        # redirect to login page
      end
    end
```

The idea being that you leave the logic out of the view, and instead either have the controller serve the logged in user the appropriate data / page or have an unauthenticated user redirected to the login page.

`current_user` is a method given to you by devise that evaluates either to the currently logged in user making the request or `nil` if the user is not logged in.

If you post your controller code, I'll file out more of my example code, I just didn't want to make it too specific at risk of being confusing.

Comment: Oh I see so `image_action` would be like a dummy action that would only be present when a logged out user is viewing the button. I wouldn't need a  `if current_user` since a `current_user` will never have access to this action because I am using jquery to toggle a modal for logged in users.

Comment: I wasn't thinking that exactly, less a dummy action and more of a fork action where logged in users get what they asked for and unauthed users get redirected to the login page. The `if current_user` part is still important because everyone who clicks the link gets sent to the `image_action` action, so you have to be able to tell if they are logged in or not. I might not be understanding your question 100%, is this link making a synchronous or asynchronous request? If clicking on the link should just prompt a modal to show up or be redirected, you're likely going to have to render json.

Comment: In my view I have a conditional for the button where if the user is logged in, its just an html element with a click handler to trigger a modal, but for a logged out user it is a button with a link..that's what I was planning anyways.

Comment: Oh I see, the in that case you are right about not need the current_user condition. You won't need to use my solution either, just have the link point to `new_user_session_path`, and then implement a redirect from there. Here's the wiki on how to redirect after sign in with devise:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: I copied everything from that link under "redirect back to current page without oauth signin?" and it didn't work.

Comment: Editing my post now

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using `before_action :authenticate_user!` in your controller for validating logged_in users..you just need to override that method to redirect to whatever page you like e.g.

In your `application_controller.rb`,

```
def authenticate_user!
  if user_signed_in?
    super
  else
    redirect_to whatever_path
  end
end
```

Comment: This is behavior I want that is very specific to this show page. I have other pages on the site that aren't accessible to logged out users. I wouldn't want all of these other pages to redirect to this show action in my items controller.

Comment: It won't..you just need to redirect to the page where user tried to access non loggedin..you don't have to hard code redirection but generalise it to handle any page

Comment: The page the user is trying to access is the page the user is currently on. A logged in user clicking the button will open a modal. A logged out user clicking the button needs to be directed to the log in page so they can log in then be redirected back to this page so they can open the modal once they are logged in.